# jQuery Droppable only within matching parent ID

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a calendar-like div structure, like the following:

```
<div id="year">
   <div id="quarter">
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="week">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="week">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="quarter">
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="month">
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="week">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
         <div id="week">
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="week">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="quarter">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
            <div id="day"><p id="xmarks" class="month">X</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

What I need to do is allow the dragging of p elements only within the given class value compared to parent ID value. For instance, I can only move p elements where class="month" within the SAME MONTH based on the parent ID value = "month" - I cannot move a  element to a different month. The same holds true for  and ; I can only move within the current week or current quarter, respectively. I can move quarter p elements ANYWHERE within the same parent div id="quarter", but cannot move it outside that quarter.

Thanks.

Comment: ID's have to be unique. Change ID's to class. If you have duplicate ID's your html is not valid, hence you'll see unexpected result's

Comment: That really doesn't help my problem. I am asking for help on the jQuery in which I can bind one of the p tags to either week, month or quarter. Assume I used classes if that makes it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the divs(month, year,..) as droppable and while doing include option **accept** to restrict the droppable div's from accepting specific draggable div's.

You can try:

```
$( "#month1" ).droppable({ accept: ".month" });
```

Here is the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)

You can also try **scope** option which is additional option to accept. For this you need to set same **scope** for draggable and droppable.
Refer following API to set scope for [DROPPABLE](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-scope) and [DRAGGABLE](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scope).